# GitLab CI template job with different names

Tags: docker, yaml, gitlab-ci

Is there a way in GitLab CI to use a generic job template and run multiple instances of that job with different names?

Below I have a generic job definition in **build.yml** that specifies that the job will run in stage **build** and it will run docker build with the given Dockerfile.

I want to be able to run several builds (in parallel, but I excluded that for now to keep the configuration as clean as possible) with different names that are based on this build template. Example in **build_a.yml** and **build_b.yml** where I set a specific variable for the job that specifies which Dockerfile to use.

And in the main file **gitlab-ci.yml** i want to include these specific jobs (**build_a** and **build_b**).

common.yml

```yaml
image:
  name: docker:dind
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - build
```

build.yml

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -f $DOCKER_FILE
```

build_a.yml

```yaml
include: 'build.yml'
build:
  variables:
    DOCKER_FILE: DockerfileA
```

build_b.yml

```yaml
include: 'build.yml'
build:
  variables:
    DOCKER_FILE: DockerfileB
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
  - 'common.yml'
  - 'build_a.yml'
  - 'build_b.yml'
```

The problem is that when I include these build jobs they have the same job name, and the first job (**build_a**) will be overwritten by the second job (**build_b**) in the resulting Yaml file.

Is there another way of doing this that I have missed in the documentation or other similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve the above issue is to use the **extends** keyword to extend the job configuration in the specific build files.

The below update will create 3 build jobs (**.build**, **build_a** and **build_b**), and the runner will exclude the job named **".build"**, so that only **build_a** and **build_b** will be executed.

common.yml

```yaml
image:
  name: docker:dind
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - build
```

build.yml

```yaml
.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -f $DOCKER_FILE
```

build_a.yml

```yaml
include: 'build.yml'
build_a:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    DOCKER_FILE: DockerfileA
```

build_b.yml

```yaml
include: 'build.yml'
build_b:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    DOCKER_FILE: DockerfileB
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
  - 'common.yml'
  - 'build_a.yml'
  - 'build_b.yml'
```